# Centered text and justified

Tags: html, html-table

Any one can help me with this. I don't get why my text is justified but not centered. On big screens it is fine, but on the iPhone screen it is justified but slightly to the left of the screen. How can I center the text and make it justified at the same time? Please help me rectify the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
    <!-- DELETE AND REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN TITLE IF NOT USING MAILCHIMP -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
  <style type="text/css">
 @media (max-width: 700px){
  .responsive{
   width:100% !important;
   padding-left:2% !important;
   padding-right:2% !important;
   text-align:center-justify !important;
   margin-left:auto !important;
   margin-right:auto !important;
  }

} @media (max-width: 700px){
  .height{
   height:auto !important;
   text-align:center !important;
  }

} @media (max-width: 700px){
  .responsive img{
   width:100% !important;
   height:auto !important;
   text-align:center !important;
  }

} @media (max-width: 700px){
  *{
   font-size:12px;
  }

}</style></head>
  <body bottommargin="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <!-- START SECTION ONE -->
    
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;border-bottom:1px solid #707070;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <table align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:620px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table align="center" style="width:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" align="right" style="padding:10px;text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-size:10px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;">
                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/8522c4a9-c0fd-445f-9e6a-413d2fb16b7b.jpeg" width="90%" border="0" alt="logo.png">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsive">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" width="100%" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;line-height:20px;" class="responsive">
                            
                            <!-- your navigation bar below -->
                            
                            <a style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/about">
                              ABOUT US
                            </a>
                            
                            <a style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/about#!contact">
                              BROKERS
                            </a>
                            
                            <a style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/home#!contact">
                              CONTACT
                            </a>
                            
                            <a style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" href="www.">
                              PROPERTIES
                            </a>
                            
                            <!-- your navigation bar above -->
                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- END SECTION ONE -->
    <!-- START SECTION TWO -->
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;border-bottom:1px solid #707070;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;">
                <table style="width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <!----------------------- PHOTO 1 ----------------------->
                      <table align="center" style="width:100%;height:auto;" class="responsive">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="100%" align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" class="responsive padding-bottom-image">
                            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/e45c27ca-a768-464b-8f17-cca76f8ff0af.gif" width="600" height="280" alt="gif">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <!----------------------------- PHOTO 1 ----------------------->
                      <table align="center" style="width:100%;min-width:250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" class="responsive height">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:20px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:2px;" class="responsive padding">
                            
                            TIPS FOR INSTAGRAM
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:16px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:4px;" class="responsive padding">
                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="justify" style="font-size:14px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" class="responsive">
                            Did you know that in 2017 Instagram saw the fastest user growth rate in its
                            history — instead of slowing down, it’s actually growing faster these days. Instagram is the platform to beat right now. People are there, the growth is there, the
                            engagement is happening, and the creative and advertising tools are available to all.
                            
                          </td>
                          <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:16px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:4px;" class="responsive padding">
                            
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" style="padding:30px 0px 10px 0px;font-size:15px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:4px;" class="responsive padding">
                                                
                                                <hr style="width:30px;background-color:#707070;color:#707070;height:0px;">
                                                LET'S MEET | DISCUTONS
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;line-height:10px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1px;padding:0px 0 20px 0;" class="responsive">
                                                
                                                emailadress
                                                
                                                <!-- END SECTION FOUR -->
                                                <!-- START SECTION FIVE -->
                                                <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                      <table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="center" style="padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                            <table style="width:100%;max-width:600px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                  <table align="center" style="width:90%;" class="responsive">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                      <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;line-height:16px;font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;padding:15px 0 5px 0;">
                                                                        © 2018. Mellor Group, All rights reserved.
                                                                      </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                      <td align="center" style="font-size:12px;line-height:16px;font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;padding:5px 0 15px 0;">
                                                                      </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                  </table>
                                                                  <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->
                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;">
                                                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                      <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                                                          <a href="http://www.mellorgroup.ca/en/home" style="display:inline-block;" target="_blank"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/0c0a64f4-17ae-4251-8e57-c0f132bd1453.png" width="25" height="25" alt="facebook icon"></a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                                                          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/etienne.mellor" style="display:inline-block;" target="_blank"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/121a7d4d-aff4-46db-b815-7ba26a405185.png" width="25" height="25" alt="facebook icon"></a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        
                                                                        <td align="center" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                                                          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/etienne-d-mellor-57866a15/" style="display:inline-block;" target="_blank"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/4ef59692-55f3-4b8f-a966-5290c968d50a.png" width="25" height="25" alt="linkedin icon"></a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        
                                                                        <td align="center" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                                                          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/royallepageheritage/" style="display:inline-block;" target="_blank"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/1eeeed4b-1377-4f25-89f0-e87215193ac5.png" width="25" height="25" alt="instagram icon"></a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                                                          <a href="https://twitter.com/heritagerlp" style="display:inline-block;" target="_blank"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/36510e9f-1dc7-4f88-b29c-3d7c0d6d263b.png" width="25" height="25" alt="twitter icon"></a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="center" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                                                          <a href="tel:514-934-1818" style="display:inline-block;" target="_blank"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6dd6910c9a28d84d5d2a32040/images/9625317f-135b-4d08-bf8f-f242958c85cd.png" width="25" height="25" alt="phone"></a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                      </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                  </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                              <!-- END SOCIAL BUTTONS -->
                                                            </table>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I expanded your code snippet to full screen and inspected it with the developer tools window, and I noticed that this `<td>` element is taking up space on the right side of the screen, which seems to be what is causing your other elements to shift off-center:

```
<td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:16px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:4px;" class="responsive padding">
</td>
```

I tried just deleting that element, and it seemed to do the trick. The element is nested inside this `<tr>` element along with your paragraph of text:

```
<tr>
    <td align="justify" style="font-size:14px;line-height:24px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;letter-spacing:1px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" class="responsive">
        Did you know that in 2017 Instagram saw the fastest user growth rate in its
        history — instead of slowing down, it’s actually growing faster these days. Instagram is the platform to beat right now. People are there, the growth is there, the
        engagement is happening, and the creative and advertising tools are available to all.
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;font-size:16px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:4px;" class="responsive padding">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is a screenshot of that element highlighted:

[image]